# Does the new Macbook Air have a 1000 battery cycle limit?

Tags: battery, macbook-pro

I know that since 2009 Apple has been advertising the 1000 battery cycles that'll last for around 5 years under normal use for Macbooks and Macbook Pros. I don't see them advertising it in the new Macbook Air, is it the case that they have the same long lasting battery or not?

Comment: Given that the new Apple Silicon CPUs use less energy, the battery is going to last even longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes their design limit is to exceed 1,000 full charge cycles. [Quoting from Apple on batteries](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html):

> The built-in battery of your MacBook,
> MacBook Pro or MacBook Air is designed
> to deliver up to 1000 full charge and
> discharge cycles before it reaches 80
> percent of its original capacity.

I have been bowled over at how well the internal battery chemistry holds up over time. Of course, bad batteries fail prematurely all the time and need to be swapped, but my gut feel is way more of these "go the distance" than all the older removable batteries.

Comment: Ok, thanks. They didn't put it in Macbook Air's page. I'm using the battery from just the one generation before they made this 1000 cycles, and it wouldn't hold any longer than 2 hours now... Here's hoping that my new laptop will last 7 hours for 5 years...

Comment: I've had great luck taking all battery issues to apple stores. They have good tools and sometimes I pay for a battery, sometimes they cover it based on circumstances even once out of warranty. Just knowing how it's doing is nice. All airs have the designed for 1k cycles AFAIK.